# Regex trying to get some text after text doesn't work

Tags: java, regex

I got this code which should retrieve the id value from the url.:

```
        String xmlTag = "http://www.facebook.com/profile.asp?id=123456789";
        xmlTag = xmlTag.replaceAll("/", "//");

        //regex variables
        final String regexUrl = "(?:(?:http|https):\\//\\//)?(?:www.)?facebook.com\\//(?:(?:\\w)*#!\\//)?(?:[?\\w\\-]*\\//)?(?:profile.asp\\?id=(?=\\d.*))?([\\w\\-]*)?";
        final Pattern patternUrl = Pattern.compile(regexUrl);
        final Matcher matcherUrl = patternUrl.matcher(xmlTag);  

        String urlResult = matcherUrl.group(0);         
        System.out.println("group(0) = " + urlResult);
        String regexId = "(?<=http:////www.facebook.com//profile.asp?id=).*";
        System.out.println("regexId =   " + regexId);

        final Pattern patternId = Pattern.compile(regexId);
        final Matcher matcherId = patternId.matcher(urlResult);         
        System.out.println("id = " + matcherId.matches());
```

The output should be: `123456789` which is 'true' for 'atcherId.matches()'

But instead of that i'm getting 'false' like that:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Unknown Source)
    at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:19)
```

Do I miss something here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your objective is to find id from the URL, then I would suggest a simpler regex instead of using such a long one.

**Sample:**

```
    String xmlTag = "http://www.facebook.com/profile.asp?id=123456789";
    String regexId = "\\?id=(\\d+)";
    final Pattern patternId = Pattern.compile(regexId);
    final Matcher matcherId = patternId.matcher(xmlTag);
    System.out.println("found id = " + matcherId.find());
    System.out.println("id = " + matcherId.group(1));
```

Comment: @Pshemo, you are right, since find is used instead of match, .* is not required, thanks for catching that, will fix that in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to put this:

```
(?:(?:http|https):////)?(?:www\\.)?facebook.com//(?:(?:[\w\-]*))?(?:profile.asp\?id=(?=\d.*))?([\\w\\-]*)?
```

with the sample

```
http:////www.facebook.com//profile.asp?id=123456789
```

to
http://regexpal.com/
Try use this and escape only the necessary sequences
And this worked.

---

I know this is for JS, but there shouldn't be a lot of differences

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use group you need first to make your pattern traverse text data. You can do it by calling `matches` `find` or `lookingAt`.

It is necessary because there can be many substrings which can match our regex, so `group` can't know which one we want to recieve.
So lets say that we have regex `a(\w)` which finds two letters where first one is `a` and we want to get only second one. For data like `abacad` what should be result of calling `group()` on matcher? Should it be `b` `c` or `d`? Regex can't know which one of them we are interested in, and `group` can return only one value at a time. So it is our job to make regex engine traverse and `find` its match before we will be able to use it (or some part of it).